# Связка моделей объект - фотографии

Tags: python, django-admin, django

Пишу сайт на Django, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть 2 модели

```
class Object(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='заголовок', max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField(verbose_name='описание')

class Picture(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Object, verbose_name='объект')
```

Как сделать:
 1. Что бы в админке(стандартной) фотографии добавлялись на странице Объекта
 2. Какие есть предложения по этому коду?

```
def get_photos_as_html(self)
    pictures = Picture.objects.filter(obj=self)
    html = ["<img src='%s' />" % (x.url) for x in pictures].join("\n")
    return html
```

Comment: по 2му - код приемлемый, но почему не шаблон? если нужен JSON почему ответ не кодируется в него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ [во втором шаге для начинающих](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02.html#adding-related-objects).